# Executing powershell remotely issue

Tags: powershell, tfs, build, passwords

Hi when i try to do some code:

```
$Username = 'us'
$Password = 'password'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList   $Username,$pass



powershell.exe  -command "Invoke-Command -ComputerName server.com -scriptblock {pathCopyAndUnzip.ps1} -Credential $Cred"
```

This prompt me for a password but when i try to run this command like here (without powershell.exe):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server.com -scriptblock {pathCopyAndUnzip.ps1} -Credential $Cred
```

it works without prompt. Do you know how to resolve that? I need to use option 1 because this command is runned from TFS build definition file like here:

```
  <Exec Command="powershell.exe -command &quot;Invoke-Command -ComputerName $(Server) -scriptblock {path} -Credential $Cred&quot;" Condition="'$(RunTests)' == 'True'"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pipe the commands to powershell.exe like this:

```
'$Username = "us"; $Password = "password"; $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force; $Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList   $Username,$pass; Invoke-Command -ComputerName server.com -scriptblock {pathCopyAndUnzip.ps1} -Credential $Cred' | powershell.exe  -command -
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put your script into it's own file and then call that from TFS rather inline code.

C:\folder\script.ps1:

```
Param(
    [string]$Username,
    [string]$Password,
    [string]$OtherParam,
)

$Password = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$Password

Invoke-Command -ComputerName server.com -FilePath "C:\folder\CopyAndUnzip.ps1 -Something $OtherParam" -Credential $Cred
```

Then call it like so:

```
<Exec Command="powershell.exe -command "C:\folder\script.ps1 -username user10 -password P@55w0rd -OtherParam Whatever" Condition="'$(RunTests)' == 'True'"/>
```

Comment: some kind of inception ;) this is an resolution but i need also to give a parameters to that script inside a script

Comment: You can use parameters to pass input from command line to the script, I've shown params in both the script itself (user/pass) and the other script that it calls (OtherParam).

Answer (score 0):

```
<Exec Command="$(PsExecPath) -accepteula \\$(Server) cmd /C  powershell -File FILEPATH " Condition="'$(RunTests)' == 'True'"/>
```

I used old good psExec :) Everything is work now.